# EXECUTE will update only once

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have the following code (written in python for sqlite3):

```
UPDATE Products set quantity = CASE
WHEN (SELECT quantity FROM Activities WHERE product_id = id) < 0
    THEN quantity = CASE
        WHEN quantity + (SELECT quantity FROM Activities WHERE product_id = id) >= 0
            THEN quantity + (SELECT quantity FROM Activities WHERE product_id = id)
        ELSE
            quantity
        END
WHEN (SELECT quantity FROM Activities WHERE product_id = Products.id) > 0
    THEN quantity + (SELECT quantity FROM Activities WHERE product_id = id)
ELSE 
    quantity
END
WHERE id IN (SELECT product_id FROM Activities)
```

that's what i'm trying to do here:

I have a database which stores :-

- Products table (which contains the columns "id" and "quantity") and
- Activities table (which contains the columns "product_id" and "quantity").

Consider the following :-

if Activities.quantity[i] > 0, that this is a batch of products coming into storage, so we just add it to the quantity of the matching product in Products table.

if Activities.quantity[i] < 0 than this represents a sell, so we first need to check the the matching product's quantity is enough (there's no less quantity than the sell quantity).

I try to update the database at once, for example let's assume we have a product in Products table with `id:1` and `quantity:0` on line i, that means Products.quantity[i] = 0.

now assume a sequence of rows in Activities table:

- `[(product_id:1, quantity -20),
  (product_id:1, quantity 100),
  (product-id:1 , quantity: -200),
  (product-id:1 , quantity: -10)]`

there's the expected result from the perspective of the entry in Activities.quantity which correspond to `product-id:1` after calculating this line:

- step one: Products.quantity[i] + Activities.quantity[0] = 0 - 100 < 0, so update is skipped
- step two: Products.quantity[i] + Activities.quantity[0] = 0 + 100 > 0, so make the update: Products.quantity[i] = 100
- step three: Products.quantity[i] + Activities.quantity[0] = 100 - 200 < 0, so update is skipped
- step four: Products.quantity[i] + Activities.quantity[0] = 90 - 10 > 0, so make the update: Products.quantity[i] = 90

any help would be appreciated,
thanks

**UPDATE:**
I edited the example so the flow would be more clear

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example here.  It is difficult to follow your exact problem.

Comment: I made an update to the example, feel free to share your thoughts and solutions :)